# Override BigQuery DSN Advanced Settings

Tags: google-bigquery, odbc, powerbi, dax

I've updated Simbda driver for BigQuery to latest version (ODBC Version: 03.80; Driver Version: 2.2.0.1005) and faced the following problem for Power BI DSN Connection -

```
ODBC: 
    ERROR [HY000] 
    [Simba][BigQuery] (100) 
        Error interacting with REST API: 
            Already Exists: Dataset PROJECT_ID:_bqodbc_temp_tables
```

I've figured out Simba tried to create dataset for large results (it's name configured via [LargeResultDataSetId](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/mac/content/odbc/bq/options/ui/largeresultdatasetid.htm) option and is *_bqodbc_temp_tables* by default).

The problem seem to be caused by the fact I need multiple near-simalteneous updates for different tables and datasets - the driver tried to create new temporary dataset for each new connection without explicit check of its existance and failes with already exists error. I've tried to unset this parameter value via DSN settings, but in that case default name is used when Standard SQL dialect is selected.

I've tried to define specific value via connection string as follows, but it is ignored for some reason:

```
= Odbc.DataSource(
    "dsn=" 
        & dsn_name 
        & ";LargeResultDataSetId=_tmp_results_" & report_suffix, 
    [
        HierarchicalNavigation=true, 
        CreateNavigationProperties = false
    ]
)
```

So, is there any **guaranteed** option to override default DSN settings?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into same problem. The issue seem to be table prep version conflicts.
Initially I had created the flow on Windows machine with prep 2019.1 version and tried to run it on MacBook with prep version 2020.1 and I got:

> Error interacting with REST API: 
>               Already Exists: Dataset PROJECT_ID:_bqodbc_temp_tables

I rebuilt the flow on Mac and the problem disappeared.